# how does this two varibles exchange using one line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I do not know how to learn demo 2,because it's difficult for me.

```js
//demo1.js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c;

c = b;
b = a;
a = c;

log(a);   // a = 2
log(b);   // b = 1   I can read this one.


//demo 2.js

var a = 1, b = 2;
a = [b][b = a, 0];   // why? '0' is a varible?
console.log(a,b) //output a = 2, b =1
```

Comment: Although this is neat, please do not learn this as something you should ever actually do. It is not quality code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//   v---- 1.  v---- 3.
a = [b][b = a, 0];
//      ^---^-- 2.
```

1. Put the value of the `b` variable in a new Array.
2. The next set of square brackets is the *member operator* used for getting the index. In this case, that space is being used to reassign the value of the `a` variable to the `b` variable. This can be done because the original value of `b` is safely in the Array *(from step 1.)*.
3. Separated by comma operator, the `0` index is then used as the actual value of the Array being retrieved, which if you'll recall is the original `b` value. This is then assigned to `a` via the first `=` assignment on the line.

So to summarize, `b` is put in the Array, and is retrieved via the `0` index and assigned to `a` on the left, but not before `a` is assigned to `b` *(borrowing the space of the `[]` member operator)*.

---

This could also be written like this:

```
a = [b, b = a][0];
```

Only difference now is that the second index of the Array is used to do the assignment. Probably a little clearer like this.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator in Javascript evaluates its left operand, throws it away and returns its right operand after evaluating. Its only use is when the left operand has a side-effect (like modifying a variable's value) but you don't want its result.

[b] defines an array containing b.

[b = a, 0] evaluates b = a - so b now contains the value of a. Then it throws it away. Then it takes the element at index 0 of [b] - returning b. a now contains the value of b that was stored there, rather than the up-to-date value of b, so our swap is successful (albeit obfuscated).